# A property like QList<T> in PyQt5 for QML

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlist

In C++ I would often use `QList<QObject*>` or `QList<QString>` as an immutable property to export to qml code for presentation. However, I can't find how to do this in pyqt5, the documentation doesn't have anything about templated classes.

There are `QAbstractItemModel` and `QAbstractListModel`, but they are too much boilerplate. There also is `QStringListModel`, but it's not applicable for everything.

Also there is a `QQmlListProperty` which works nicely in Python, but that's difficult to manipulate in C++ code.

So for example I have this QML component:

```
Row {
    ListView {
        model: pyModel.urls
        delegate: Label {
            text: modelData
        }
    }
    ListView {
        model: pyModel.objects
        delegate: Label {
            text: modelData.text
        }
    }
    PyModel {
        id: pyModel
    }
}
```

What types should I write in my python properties for them to work?

```py
class PyModel(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    @pyqtProperty('???', constant=True)
    def urls(self):
        return [QUrl("file:///etc/shadow")]

    @pyqtProperty('???', constant=True)
    def objects(self):
        return [OtherObject("someData")]
```

Comment: In PyQt5 you can use a simple list [].

Comment: That would be cool. What's the syntax in the `@pyqtProperty` declaration?

Answer (score 2):

In PyQt5 you can generally use a simple Python list to replace `QList`; in the case of `pyqtProperty` you can define it as follows:

```
@pyqtProperty(list)
def someProperty(self):
    return self._someList
```

Comment: Alright, that works when I'm exporting data from python, but it doesn't work when assigning a property in python class from qml, i get an empty list in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Found a piece of code in some mailing list that worked for me:

```py
@pyqtProperty('QList<QUrl>')
def someProperty(self):
    return self._someList
```

When accepting data from qml, this qlist works like a python list.

Comment: `QList<QUrl>` is not compatible with `QList<QObject *>`, QUrl is not a QObject,  Are you sure that your data was `QList <QObject *>`?

Comment: Oh yeah you're right. It seems I worded the question incorrectly, but what I needed was a syntax to describe a property that is a vector of 'something', be it qobject-derived or a qgadget. And Isma's answer and this finding were both what I needed.

Comment: Using QList <QUrl> only works if you have a list of url (QML) or QUrl (c ++ / python), but if you have a list of Items it will not work, if you have a string it could work in certain cases and in others it does not, if you have real, int will not work, if you have QtObject it will not work, if you have Component it will not work either. So your question is very generic and your answer is very limited.

Comment: I know that. I only wrote QUrl here as an example from my piece of code. It works with other types in other places of my code.